# Можно ли в docker запустить контейнер с nodejs, подождать пока всё запуститься и затем заменить этим контейнером предыдущий?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Использую docker вместе с docker-compose в проекте, при обновлении кода приходится останавливать контейнер с предыдущим образом, и запускать уже новый с текущим. Собираю образ я заранее, а вот сам nodejs в контейнере запускается где-то две минуты в которые сайт лежит. Есть ли способ запустить контейнер с новым образом, подождать пока он запуститься и затем заменить им старый? При том чтобы порты не конфликтовали друг с другом.

Comment: Да, достаточно при готовности нового инстанса начать принимать соединения прекратить прием соединений в старом инстансе, оставив его продолжать обрабатывать уже активные соединения и сразу начать принимать соединения в новом инстансе. При грамотной реализации простой составит не более нескольких миллисекунд.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо большое! Сам каким-то образом забыл про такую возможность

Comment: @user7860670 Ещё вопрос, могу ли я запустить контейнер через docker-compose при этом не подсоединять его к сети после запуска?

Comment: Конечно же нет.

Comment: @user7860670 Т.е. придётся подключать новый контейнер к другой сети, а затем переподключать к основной? Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Нет, и новый, и старый контейнеры подключаются к одной сети.

Comment: @user7860670 Тогда я не совсем понимаю как я могу сделать то что вы написали. Можете, пожалуйста, опубликовать более подробный ответ или комментарий, с тем как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Ну для начала вам необходимо реализовать в своем коде механизм прекращения приема соединений при поступлении какого-то внешнего сигнала. Хотя бы посредством служебного локального сокета. ¿Это понятно?

Comment: @user7860670 Хотелось бы реализовать это средствами только docker, если такое возможно

Comment: Реализовать такое средствами докер не получится.

Comment: @user7860670 Очень жаль

Comment: @user7860670 Вообще мне кажется что такое спокойно можно реализовать через докеровские сети, я изначально и подумал что ваш первый комментарий об этом и говорит